# How to compare textarea value with text in a div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple typewriter in which the user needs to type a given text. This text written by the user will be compared with that given text and if it matches the background color of that given text will turn green.

I have this div:

```
<div class="textToWrite">this is a text</div>
```

and this text area:

```
<textarea id="textarea-space" rows="10" cols="75" placeholder="type here your text"></textarea>
```

I have a javascript code with a eventlistener on the textarea:

```
textarea1.addEventListener("keypress", checkInputWithText,false);
```

whenever a key in the textarea is pressed it checks if the text is the same as the value of the textToWrite div:

```
function checkInputWithText(e){
   if(textarea1.readOnly == false){
     let textToWrite = document.querySelector(".textToWrite");
     if(textarea1.value.trim() == textToWrite.textContent.trim()){
       textToWrite.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     }
   }
}
```

The problem is that the compare does not work. Can somebody please explain what I am doing wrong, so please not only give a solution but also an explanation so that I can learn.

```js
function checkInputWithText(e) {
  if (textarea1.readOnly == false) {
    let textToWrite = document.querySelector(".textToWrite");
    if (textarea1.value.trim() == textToWrite.textContent.trim()) {
      textToWrite.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textToWrite">this is a text</div>
<textarea id="textarea-space" rows="10" cols="75" placeholder="type here your text"></textarea>
```

For the complete code please check:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yx5f0gb/1/)

Comment: How to type when it is readonly

Comment: Sorry for that, in the complete code I have a button which removes the readonly

Comment: Where is the function called? Please update the snippet to a [mcve]

Comment: This works for me when you remove `readonly` assuming you're picking up the elements correctly, and assigning the event listeners properly.

Comment: textarea.value is the content of the textarea. There is no .text() on a string

Comment: @Andy textarea.value="xxx" will work just fine. I think you are all confusing the issue due to a major JS error in the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you meant to do this?

```js
let field; // save the field
let textToWrite; // we only want to define it once
function checkInputWithText(e) {
  if (this.value.trim() == textToWrite) {
    field.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // to make sure the fields exist. 
  field = document.querySelector(".textToWrite");
  textToWrite= field.textContent.trim();
  document.getElementById("textarea-space").addEventListener("input", checkInputWithText);
});
```

```html
<div class="textToWrite">this is a text</div>
<textarea id="textarea-space" rows="10" cols="75" placeholder="type here your text"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, this works. Why did you use load and input and not for example checking on keypress?

Comment: input handles pasting and the load handler is to make sure the object exists when the event handler is assigned - you can remove the load if the code is after the textarea

Comment: Also I save the comparison field and do not retrieve it on each keystroke

Comment: Does every eventlistener which handles things like input of the user need to put under the load?

Comment: Yes, or just after the html that defines them - so you can have all the script before the `</body>` tag